# java util zip ZipException: duplicate entry

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, error-handling, exception

While running the project I'm getting this error

> Error:Execution failed for task ':..........'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: javax/annotation/CheckForNull.class

This is how my app:gradle looks like :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.sample.Example"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 24
    multiDexEnabled true
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile (project(':library')){
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
compile (project(':facebookLib')){
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.20.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
compile files('libs/CWAC-SackOfViewsAdapter.jar')
compile files('libs/FlurryAgent.jar')
compile files('libs/google-api-client-1.15.0-rc.jar')
compile files('libs/google-api-client-android-1.15.0-rc.jar')
compile files('libs/google-api-services-androidpublisher-v1-rev15-1.15.0-rc.jar')
compile files('libs/google-http-client-1.15.0-rc.jar')
compile files('libs/google-http-client-android-1.15.0-rc.jar')
compile files('libs/google-http-client-jackson-1.15.0-rc.jar')
compile files('libs/google-http-client-jackson2-1.15.0-rc.jar')
compile files('libs/google-oauth-client-1.15.0-rc.jar')
compile files('libs/google-oauth-client-java6-1.15.0-rc.jar')
compile files('libs/httpmime-4.2.jar')
compile files('libs/in-app-purchasing-1.0.3.jar')
compile files('libs/jackson-core-2.1.3.jar')
compile files('libs/jackson-core-asl-1.9.11.jar')
compile files('libs/json_simple-1.1.jar')
compile files('libs/jsr305-1.3.9.jar')
compile files('libs/picasso-2.1.1.jar')
compile files('libs/signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.1.jar')
compile files('libs/signpost-core-1.2.1.1.jar')
compile files('libs/signpost-jetty6-1.2.1.1.jar')
compile files('libs/twitter4j-core-4.0.1.jar')
compile files('libs/amazon-device-messaging-1.0.1.jar')
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

volley:gradle

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 17
buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 8
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
}
```

library:gradle

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 16
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 4
    targetSdkVersion 4
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
}
```

facebookLib:gradle

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 17
buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 8
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
}
```

Can someone suggest a way out of this error ? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
com.android.support:support-v4:_____
```

This library is used multiple times. So here's what you can do. do this on either your library's gradle or facebooklib's gradle:

```
compile(project(':facebookLib')) {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
```

OR

```
compile(project(':library')) {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
```

Tip: You should make a gradle task to print your dependencies when building and take a look at it. See if there is anything you can remove/improve

EDIT:

run this command in the terminal tab of your Android Studio.

```
./gradlew app:dependencies
```

This will print out all dependencies and their (sub)dependencies. Look through it and see which of the dependency is called twice where.

Every time you see the same library twice, you have to use the `exclude` method showed above to exclude that moudle or group.

See here for more details. It's nice and simple explanation.  https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-find-dependencies-particular-dependency-gradle-hesamedin-kamalan-1

Comment: getting an error while gradle sync

> Could not find method exclude() for arguments [{module=support-v4}] on project ':library' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Comment: @Shahal look at my edit. It's project so you need an extra set of parentheses. i forgot that :\

Comment: getting the same exception . but exclude() didn't through any error .

Comment: you also have the same library in your main project so exclude it from both projects, `facebookLib`and `library`. YOu have a long list of dependencies and it's such a common library. I'm sure some other library or project is using it too

Comment: added exclude code to both my projects still getting the same exception.
ps:  i have edited my above code.

Comment: @Shahal i'm gonna look at which of your other lib have same libs but remember to remove the `compile project(':library')` towards the end of your dependencies. You are compiling that project twice now

Comment: sorry , that's just a error when i wrote the question . I have only one     'compile project(':library')' in my code

Comment: @Shahal yea i figured. We all do that lol. also I edited my answer

Comment: is it gradlew instead of gradle ?

Comment: i edited my answer. it's different for gradle wrapper. Also, remember to change "app" to your module's name if it's not named "app"

Comment: There was few errors in two of my libs .when i removed it , it worked fine . Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Run the following to find the duplicates

```
task findDuplicates {
   doLast {
      String findMe = 'javax/annotation/CheckForNull.class'
      configurations.compile.files.each { file ->
         if (file.name.endsWith('.jar')) {
            def classMatches = zipTree(file).matching {
               include findMe
            }.files
            if (!classMatches.empty) {
               println "Found $findMe in $file ${classMatches.size()} time(s)"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I can't run the project in the first place to do all these.

Comment: yes you can, run `gradle findDuplicates` after adding my snippet to your `build.gradle`

Comment: I get "Error:(28, 1) Execution failed for task ':findDuplicates'.
> Could not get unknown property 'runtime' for configuration container."

Comment: Changed to `configurations.compile.x`

Answer (score 1):

You could do a dependencies cleanup in Android Studio. When doing this you will find the referenced libraries per module in tree view. In that way you will find which dependencies are generating the duplicate entry error. 
Search in your project which files are using o referencing CheckForNull.class. Take note of the package who contain it.

Open the terminal window in your project and excecute the follow command

```
gradlew clean app:dependencies
```

Please note that ALL dependencies will be remove and re-downloaded. If you have a lot of gradle libraries it may take a couple of minutes to download again. After that you will find a summary  where you could filter the package you fin. In my case the problem was with the apache.commons package. I do the filter and find something like this:

```
+--- com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.4.0
|    +--- com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.4.0 (*)
|    +--- com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-kms:2.4.0
|    |    \--- com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.4.0 (*)
|    +--- org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2
|    |    \--- commons-io:commons-io:1.3.2 -> 2.4
|    +--- commons-io:commons-io:2.4
|    \--- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk16:1.44
```

In my case it was a duplicate entry generated by AWS Android SDK, refered to the commons-io dependency.

Finally, just make the exclusion in your gradle file like this (Remember that in my case it was a diffenrt dependency):

```
compile('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.4.0')
        {
            exclude group: 'org.apache.commons'
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to compile same dependencies in each separate module, as  your app:gradle is compiling
 `'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'` 
which has already been compiled in your library gradle as  `'com.android.support:support-v4:18.+`' where I can see you have added library module as a dependency to app:gradle, here you are trying to replicate it. Same goes with other modules also.
Unless they are independent.

Tip: Also don't use anonymous versions like `'com.android.support:support-v4:18.+'`instead use appropriate versions.

Answer (score 0):

Build -> Rebuild Project in Android Studio fixed it for me.