# java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: javax/inject/Inject.class

Tags: java, android, android-studio, dependency-injection

I have seen similar responses to the below question. Sorry but i could not fixed it out trying multiple things so I am asking it again.
Whenever I am trying to build my app, the gradle build throws me the below error stating ...due to duplicate entry of javax/Inject class.
This only occurred when I am trying to put `compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-jdk-http:2.9'` in my `build.gradle` file; This package is necessary for `javax.ws.rs.*` services.

I tried running the `gradlew clean` command in my root directory, it says that build is successful but when I am building my application again it started throwing the error again.
Can you please help on the below error:

```
*Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: javax/inject/Inject.class*
```

Below is my app gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.usfca.studentrecordsverifycation"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    maven { url 'http://maven.restlet.com' }
    maven { url 'https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/' }
    maven { url 'http://download.java.net/maven/2/' }
    maven { url 'http://download.java.net/maven/1' }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'log4j:log4j:1.2.17'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.madgag:sc-light-jdk15on:1.47.0.3'
    compile 'com.cloudinary:cloudinary-http44:1.4.5'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-jdk-http:2.9'
    compile 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6'
}
```

Below is my Project gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Duplicate. Look at the answer here. See the "edit" in the answer. Try it out and it should fix it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39957924/java-util-zip-zipexception-duplicate-entry?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: i used gradlew app:dependencies to find out if there is any such dependency exists, i just got no depedencies for all except the below: +--- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:2.3.0-b05
|    |    |    +--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
|    |    |    +--- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-utils:2.3.0-b05
|    |    |    |    \--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1

Comment: can you explain it please how to fix it as this could not be fixed still.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I created a sample project with all those dependencies and I got a different error.

So if you are still getting the `ZipException` error, you have some jars in your lib folder that we are not aware of?

Here's the error I got:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE
```

If you are getting a similar error, all you need to do is add the following to your `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
    }

    buildTypes {
        ....
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }
}
```

If this doesn't make any difference, do you have any jar libraries in your project? If so, we need to see the list.

**EDIT:**

I can't know for sure if it will work because I am not getting the same error. In your dependencies, change to this:

```
compile ('org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-jdk-http:2.9') {
    exclude group: 'javax.inject', module: 'javax.inject'
}
```

Comment: No jar package is there in lib folder. above does not helps

Comment: That's very strange. I'm not able to reproduce the error with same libraries, same build and compile version.

Comment: Do you know any other way to fix it?

Comment: ok the above resolves the issue but it gives Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig$State$3 when I am clicking on the button which in behind invokes that package

Comment: can you say why NoSuchClassFoundException even the package is there

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. I am still unsure about why you would get this error and my project doesn't. Any reason why you are still using the 2.9 version of the lib? Maybe try updating to the latest 2.23.2 lib. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-jdk-http/2.23.2 Also, I would recommended, delete all contents of your build folder, clean the project and try again

Answer (score 0):

This error means that the class `javax.inject.Inject` is being included twice in your apk when the dexer runs. That is, this exact same class is coming from 2 different dependencies. One of them is probably `org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-jdk-http:2.9` because it happens after you added it.
If you CMD+O (jump to class) on Android Studio, you should be able to see the 2 versions of this class and see where they are coming from. Make sure you select the checkbox that allows it to show classes included from your dependencies. Once you open them, hover over the file tab and you'll see a tooltip with the artifact name. That is gonna be the dependency that's including that class.
Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? Could you look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43277745/error-while-compiling-react-native-duplicate-entry-javax-inject-inject-class) question as well?