# Error while compiling React-native duplicate entry: javax/inject/Inject.class

Tags: gradle, react-native, build.gradle, gradlew

I downloaded a React-native project from the web called [react-native-obd2](https://github.com/jetbridge-io/react-native-obd2). Before I got started I just wanted to run the example that was already given in the repo but while running `react-native run-android` I am getting stuck at an error.

```
:app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: javax/inject/Inject.class
```

I have been breaking my head for over 3 hours to solve this bugger but it wouldn't go.

I have tried various solutions one of the most logical solution to me was that `javax/inject/Inject.class` is being called twice somewhere.

So I typed this command to get the gradle classpath.
`./gradlew -q dependencies app:dependencies --configuration compile`

```
compile - Classpath for compiling the main sources.
+--- project :react-native-obd2
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1 -> 24.1.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:24.1.0
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:24.1.0
|    |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.0
|    |    |              \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:24.1.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:24.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.facebook.react:react-native:+ -> 0.34.1
|    |    +--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1 -> 24.1.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1 -> 24.1.0
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.0 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:24.1.0
|    |    +--- com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.11.0
|    |    |    +--- com.facebook.fresco:drawee:0.11.0
|    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1 -> 24.1.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- com.facebook.fresco:fbcore:0.11.0
|    |    |    +--- com.facebook.fresco:fbcore:0.11.0
|    |    |    \--- com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline:0.11.0
|    |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1 -> 24.1.0 (*)
|    |    |         +--- com.facebook.fresco:fbcore:0.11.0
|    |    |         +--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0
|    |    |         +--- com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0
|    |    |         \--- com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline-base:0.11.0
|    |    |              +--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1 -> 24.1.0 (*)
|    |    |              +--- com.facebook.fresco:fbcore:0.11.0
|    |    |              +--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0
|    |    |              \--- com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0
|    |    +--- com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline-okhttp3:0.11.0
|    |    |    +--- com.facebook.fresco:fbcore:0.11.0
|    |    |    +--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.1 -> 3.4.1
|    |    |    |    \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.9.0
|    |    |    \--- com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline:0.11.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.1.0
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.2.3
|    |    +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.0
|    |    +--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.4.1
|    |    |    \--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-ws:3.4.1
|    |    |    \--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.9.0
|    |    \--- org.webkit:android-jsc:r174650
|    +--- com.github.pires:obd-java-api:1.0-RC16
|    \--- org.roboguice:roboguice:3.+ -> 3.0.1
+--- project :react-native-vector-icons
|    \--- com.facebook.react:react-native:+ -> 0.34.1 (*)
+--- project :react-native-sp
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1 -> 24.1.0 (*)
|    \--- com.facebook.react:react-native:+ -> 0.34.1 (*)
+--- project :react-native-sensor-manager
|    \--- com.facebook.react:react-native:0.12.+ -> 0.34.1 (*)
+--- project :react-native-dialogs
|    +--- com.facebook.react:react-native:0.20.+ -> 0.34.1 (*)
|    \--- com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.8.6.2
|         +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.0 (*)
|         \--- com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.6.2
|              +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.0 (*)
|              +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.1.0 (*)
|              +--- com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.0 (*)
|              +--- me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar:library:1.1.7
|              |    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0 -> 24.1.0 (*)
|              |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:24.0.0 -> 24.1.0
|              \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:24.1.0
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1 -> 24.1.0 (*)
\--- com.facebook.react:react-native:+ -> 0.34.1 (*)
```

but I don't see javax written twice. 
It was also mentioned that check the versions of the downloaded project and your file but I couldn't find any significant difference.

Here is the build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.obd2example"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-obd2')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile project(':react-native-sp')
    compile project(':react-native-sensor-manager')
    compile project(':react-native-dialogs')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

Could anyone please guide me where to look?

**EDIT 1**
In my quest to find out where javax.inject module was used twice I did a grep -r "javax.inject" in the node_modules folder and found this

```
react-native/android/com/facebook/react/react-native/0.34.1/react-native-0.34.1.pom:      <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
react-native/android/com/facebook/react/react-native/0.34.1/react-native-0.34.1.pom:      <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
react-native/ReactAndroid/src/main/third-party/java/jsr-330/BUCK:    url = 'mvn:javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1',
react-native/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/CoreModulesPackage.java:import javax.inject.Provider;
react-native/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/bridge/ModuleSpec.java:import javax.inject.Provider;
react-native/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/shell/MainReactPackage.java:import javax.inject.Provider;
react-native/ReactAndroid/build.gradle:    compile 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'
```

Is there something wrong here? I am not very well versed with Java and gradle build system to comprehend it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `build.gradle` file, can you try changing the following line:

`compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules`

To this:

```
compile("com.facebook.react:react-native:+") {
  exclude module: 'javax.inject'
}
```

The error basically mean that the `@Inject` annotation is being included in your final APK multiple times and it's coming from different places. It's hard to pinpoint exactly where, but this transitive dependency from react-native is most likely one of the sources. Excluding it will hopefully leave you with just one "copy" of it in your final apk.

Comment: Sadly It did not work, Though it ideally should have as per the logic. Should I post something more to help debug the problem?

Comment: but if you see the dependency graph javax.inject is written only once under react-native+ in the dependency graph. So if doesn't work, probably we are looking at the wrong place

Comment: Can you try looking into your other react native dependencies too?

    compile project(':react-native-obd2')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile project(':react-native-sp')
    compile project(':react-native-sensor-manager')
    compile project(':react-native-dialogs')

You wont be able to grep them though since the dependency may be already compiled in a jar. Do you have the source code for these libs so you could inspect them?

Comment: And what exactly I am looking for? Even if they have `javax.inject` wouldn't they require it for their own use? I actually tried excluding `javax.inject` from each dependency and all times my compilation was halted asking that javax.inject is missing, please include it. So would that really help? Anyways would try to do that?

Comment: Yes you're in the right path. I'd definitely recommend excluding from every dependency and then manually adding it as a direct dependency in your project. As long as you add it manually to your project, that's all you need for it to work, it doesn't matter if you excluded it from all your other dependencies.

Comment: Okay, the problem was with bad syntax. The correct syntax to exclude is  `compile (project(':react-native-obd2')){
         exclude module: 'javax.inject'}`

Comment: Right, when you pass a closure to a Groovy method you need to explicitly add parenthesis to the arguments before it :)