# I Have an Error Android Studio: java.util.zip.ZipException duplicate entry

Tags: android, android-studio, linphone, linphone-sdk

this `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android { 
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.id.linphone"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 15
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies { 
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'],dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile project(':libmediastreamer')
    compile project(':linphone')
}
```

this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'. com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/linphone/mediastream/AACFilter.class

Comment: do you have a question? Telling us what you did to get the error would be helpful, too.

Comment: Duplicate. Search for the error first. Look at the answer here to figure out how to list all dependencies and their sub-dependencies. Compare them and see which ones are added multiple times and then exclude those dependencies. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39957924/java-util-zip-zipexception-duplicate-entry?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: that happens when I add the library media streamer, but that error does not occur with version 2.1 of android studio

Comment: yes i try and looked for all the questions here

Comment: Do you have any jar/lib in your `libs` folder?

Comment: Yes, all jars in libs folder