# Gradle DSL method not found: exclude()

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

i am using a lot of library in my project. And some libraries using same jar file therefore i writed this on build.gradle :

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.twotoasters.jazzylistview:library:1.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.4'
compile 'com.orhanobut:dialogplus:1.11@aar'
compile 'com.github.recruit-lifestyle:FloatingView:2.2'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile ('com.specyci:residemenu:1.6+'){
    exclude group: 'com.nineoldandroids', module: 'library'    }
compile files('libs/poppyview.jar'){
    exclude group: 'com.nineoldandroids', module: 'library'    }
```

}

And i am getting error : 


Error:(54, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'exclude()'
Possible causes:

The project 'DopingEng' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
Upgrade plugin to version 2.3.1 and sync project

The project 'DopingEng' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper file

The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin

Gradle already update , how can i solve this problem ?

Comment: What plugins have you applied?

Answer (score 3):

Here's the problem

```
compile files('libs/poppyview.jar'){
   exclude ... 
}
```

A file based dependency does not work in the same way as a dependency coming from a repository. There is no meta data associated with it (eg no dependency information) so there's also nothing to exclude (since there's no transitive dependencies).

Do you have the pom/ivy meta-data for `libs/poppyview.jar`? If so then you shouldn't declare it like this (I suggest a local maven repository folder). If you don't then there's nothing to exclude

Comment: if i do this : '  compile 'com.specyci:residemenu:1.6+'
    compile files('libs/poppyview.jar') ' i am getting error                                               Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'. > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/nineoldandroids/animation/Animator$AnimatorListener.class

Comment: i must write exclude , if i should not this , what can i do ?

Comment: As I said, `files(...)` dependencies don't have transitive dependencies, so there's nothing to exclude. Either the duplicate is packed inside `poppyview.jar` or it's coming from somewhere else

Comment: then how can i use this jar file ? @Lance Java

Comment: You could add a task like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39958180/1089967) to your build.gradle to see which jars contain the duplicate `com/nineoldandroids/animation/Animator$AnimatorListener.clas‌​s`

Comment: thanks , i am sorry i don't know how can i add as task this line and where? @Lance Java

Comment: And how can write i task to build.gradle for this error ? @Lance Java